# I can't start the rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I think it must be a problem related to the path.
I made the step by step of this page [https://meekgonkey.blogspot.com/2014/02/installing-ruby-rails-on-manjaro-linux.html](http://%20https://meekgonkey.blogspot.com/2014/02/installing-ruby-rails-on-manjaro-linux.html)

```
    /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/pathname.rb:20: warning: already initialized constant Pathname::TO_PATH
/home/vitaopb/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pathname-0.2.0/lib/pathname.rb:20: warning: previous definition of TO_PATH was here
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/pathname.rb:22: warning: already initialized constant Pathname::SAME_PATHS
/home/vitaopb/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pathname-0.2.0/lib/pathname.rb:22: warning: previous definition of SAME_PATHS was here
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/pathname.rb:34: warning: already initialized constant Pathname::SEPARATOR_LIST
/home/vitaopb/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pathname-0.2.0/lib/pathname.rb:34: warning: previous definition of SEPARATOR_LIST was here
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/pathname.rb:35: warning: already initialized constant Pathname::SEPARATOR_PAT
/home/vitaopb/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pathname-0.2.0/lib/pathname.rb:35: warning: previous definition of SEPARATOR_PAT was here
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/pathname.rb:41: warning: already initialized constant Pathname::ABSOLUTE_PATH
/home/vitaopb/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pathname-0.2.0/lib/pathname.rb:41: warning: previous definition of ABSOLUTE_PATH was here
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/path.rb:103:in `to_s': unexpected @path (TypeError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/path.rb:103:in `stability'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/path.rb:11:in `stable?'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/path.rb:41:in `entries_and_dirs'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/cache.rb:159:in `block (2 levels) in unshift_paths_locked'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/cache.rb:155:in `reverse_each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/cache.rb:155:in `block in unshift_paths_locked'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:47:in `block in transaction'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:45:in `synchronize'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:45:in `transaction'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/cache.rb:154:in `unshift_paths_locked'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/cache.rb:107:in `block in unshift_paths'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/cache.rb:107:in `synchronize'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/cache.rb:107:in `unshift_paths'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/change_observer.rb:21:in `unshift'
        from /home/vitaopb/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `add_lib_to_load_path!'
        from /home/vitaopb/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:95:in `inherited'
        from /home/vitaopb/Documentos/rails/app-Tes/config/application.rb:11:in `<module:AppTes>'
        from /home/vitaopb/Documentos/rails/app-Tes/config/application.rb:9:in `<main>'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /home/vitaopb/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
        from /home/vitaopb/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/vitaopb/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
        from /home/vitaopb/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `block in perform'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from /home/vitaopb/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
        from /home/vitaopb/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /home/vitaopb/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from /home/vitaopb/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from /home/vitaopb/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        from /home/vitaopb/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from /home/vitaopb/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /home/vitaopb/Documentos/rails/app-Tes/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-3.0.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-3.0.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-3.0.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-3.0.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-3.0.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-3.0.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-3.0.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from /home/vitaopb/Documentos/rails/app-Tes/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from /home/vitaopb/Documentos/rails/app-Tes/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:2:in `load'
        from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `path` related output is a warning, not an error. The error here is: "to_s': unexpected @path (TypeError)"

Comment: so is it an error in the path?

Comment: Any reason you want to use pathname 0.2.0? `Pathname` is part of ruby core library

Comment: It looks your problem is closely related [with this one](https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap/issues/374). Why don't you try running `bundle exec ruby -e 'p Bundler.bundle_path; p Bundler.bundle_path.to_s'` locally and share the result? How you're running your rails instance? have you tried `bundle exec rails s` or maybe `./bin/rails s`?. My gut feeling? this might be related with bootsnap 1.9.0 onwards, maybe try downgrading your gem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error while running `rails new <ProjectName>`. Managed to create the project using a workaround but later got the exact same error while trying to `rails s`.

For some reason `bundle exec rails s` would throw a lengthy cryptic error and end with an abort and core dump.

Uninstalling all gems and reinstalling them for my rbenv version fixed it for me.

```
$ gem uninstall -aIx

$ gem install rails -v 6.1.4.1

$ rbenv rehash
```

(At this point rbenv threw another error saying /home/.../.rbenv-shim existed, then I ran..)

```
$ rm /home/username/.rbenv/shims/.rbenv-shim
$ rbenv rehash
```